# Is it recommended practice to put a "slash" after the self parameter in Python methods?

Tags: python, methods

With the introduction of the slash character to specify [position-only arguments](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/), is it recommended to put a slash in *every* `method` after the `self` parameter?

For example:

```
class A:
    def something(self, /, some_arg):
```

Many built-in objects seem to do so (see `range`, `str.encode`, etc.).

Is there some sort of advantage (maybe security related?) in explicitly prohibiting the `self` parameter from being set as a keyword argument?  Or is this just for clarity in interface specifications?

Comment: In CPython, these builtins are implemented in C, and the Python C API is kind of awkward for passing arguments to functions, especially if you need to accept keyword arguments. It seems likely that this is more about [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) than for any other reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not generally sensible to use the [PEP-570](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/) positional-only arguments that are available since Python 3.8.

When you define a function `def foo(a, b)`,
then you can use the arguments as either positional or named arguments. All of these are equivalent:

```py
foo(1, 2)
foo(1, b=2)
foo(a=1, b=2)
foo(b=2, a=1)
```

But sometimes, you want keyword-only or positional-only arguments.

- By using a `*`, you can force keyword-only arguments.
  When we have `def foo(*, a, b)` then only `foo(a=1, b=2)` or `foo(b=2, a=1)` invocations are allowed.
- By using a `/`, you can force positional-only arguments.
  When we have `def foo(a, b, /)` then only `foo(1, 2)` invocation is allowed.

So what `def something(self, /, some_arg)` tells us is that `self` can never be passed as a keyword argument. Does this make sense? Kind of yes, but this is not really important.

You see `/` in a lot of built-in functions because these are often implemented in C code, and they don't want to support keyword arguments for efficiency and simplicity reasons.

For maintainability, it is usually a very good idea to allow keyword arguments, or even to force keyword-only arguments. In contrast, positional-only arguments make most sense in these two cases:

- You don't want to expose your parameter names as part of the public API. For example, you don't want that people can call `some_function(123)` as `some_function(internal_name=123)` because then renaming the parameter would be an API-breaking change. This doesn't really matter for methods since the `self` parameter is passed implicitly.
- You have profiled your application and the data indicates that calls to this function are performance-critical. Calls with positional-only arguments are faster on recent Python versions. But don't start using positional-only arguments everywhere as a premature optimization!